# Flexbox shrinking and not wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get two side-by-side divs to wrap using flexbox. It worked just fine for awhile whenever I just had the divs and a background color, but when I started adding more items it stopped working. The divs start shrinking and never wrap. I have tried `flex-shrinking: 0;` and other techniques I have found on other sites. Anyways here is the code:

```css
.page4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 65%;
}

.flex-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

.left {
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 45%;
  height: 500px;
}

.background {
  background-image: url('../pictures/weenies/longpaper.png');
}

.right {
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  width: 45%;
  height: 500px;
}

.wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#logopg4 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.logopg4 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page4">
  <div class="flex-content wrap">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="subs">
        <h2>Subs N'</h2>
        <h2>Sandwiches</h2>
        <div class="subsNSandwiches background">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hen">
        <h2>Hen House</h2>
        <div class="henpaper background">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="deezerts">
        <h2>DEEZERTS</h2>
        <div class="deezertspaper background">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="logopg4">
        <img src="./pictures/subs/logo2.png" id="logopg4" />
      </div>
      <div class="rabbit">
        <h2>Rabbit Fixin's</h2>
        <div class="rabbitFixins background">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="xtraFixins">
        <h2>Xtra Fixin's</h2>
        <div class="xtrapaper background">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have omitted some of the other code from the HTML file. Any insight to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined the `width` for your flex items (`.left` and `.right`) at 45%, so they will always remain 45% wide and therefore never wrap.

You can add a `min-width`  to avoid that - see my example below, where I added `min-width: 400px` to these two elements.

```css
.page4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 65%;
}

.flex-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

.left {
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
}

.background {
  background-image: url('../pictures/weenies/longpaper.png');
}

.right {
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
}

.wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#logopg4 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.logopg4 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page4">
  <div class="flex-content wrap">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="subs">
        <h2>Subs N'</h2>
        <h2>Sandwiches</h2>
        <div class="subsNSandwiches background">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hen">
        <h2>Hen House</h2>
        <div class="henpaper background">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="deezerts">
        <h2>DEEZERTS</h2>
        <div class="deezertspaper background">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="logopg4">
        <img src="./pictures/subs/logo2.png" id="logopg4" />
      </div>
      <div class="rabbit">
        <h2>Rabbit Fixin's</h2>
        <div class="rabbitFixins background">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="xtraFixins">
        <h2>Xtra Fixin's</h2>
        <div class="xtrapaper background">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see, that is why when I had it as a set width it was working. Thanks for the knowledge. I will accept this answer whenever I am capable of accepting it (5 minutes). Thank you again!